# Saving textbox name when clicked in order to input text

Tags: vb.net, textbox, controls

Hey all i am in need of some help getting my code working correctly like i am needing it to. Below is my code that when the user click on the textbox, it pops up a keyboard where they can click on any letter and it will type that letter into the textbox. Problem being is i can not seem to get the name of the text box to return so that it knows where to send the letters to.

Order in firing is:

TextBox1_MouseDown

keyboardOrPad.runKeyboardOrPad

kbOrPad.keyboardPadType

ClickLetters

Form1.putIntoTextBox

**Form1**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    Call keyboardOrPad.runKeyboardOrPad("SHOW") 'Just shows the keyboard
    Call kbOrPad.keyboardPadType("PAD", TextBox1)
End Sub

Public Sub putIntoTextBox(ByRef what2Put As String, ByRef whatBox As TextBox)
    whatBox.Text = what2Put '<-- has error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for the whatBox.text
End Sub
```

**kbOrPad class**

```
Dim theBoxName As TextBox = Nothing

Public Sub keyboardPadType(ByRef whatType As String, ByRef boxName As TextBox)
    theBoxName = boxName '<-- shows nothing here
    Dim intX As Short = 1

    If whatType = "PAD" Then
        Do Until intX = 30
            Dim theButton() As Control = Controls.Find("Button" & intX, True)

            theButton(0).Enabled = False
            intX += 1
        Loop
    ElseIf whatType = "KEYB" Then

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClickLetters(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    If btn.Text = "Backspace" Then

    Else
        Call Form1.putIntoTextBox(btn.Text, theBoxName) 'theBoxName taken from keyboardPadType
    End If
End Sub
```

Some visuals for you:

[image]
[image]

Pastebin code: http://pastebin.com/4ReEnJB0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that `theBoxName` is a [Module scoped variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx), then I would populate it like this giving you the flexibility of implementing a shared `TextBox` `MouseDown` Handler:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

    Call keyboardPadType("PAD", tb)
End Sub
```

---

Try something like this

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myKborPad As New kbOrPad

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

    Call myKborPad.keyboardPadType("PAD", tb)
End Sub
```

---

Edit Based on your PasteBin code.

I noticed you already have an instance of your keyboardPadType declared in your Module, use that instead of what I said earlier. That code should look like:

remove:
    Dim myKborPad As New kbOrPad

and use the theKbOrPad that you created in your module like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

    Call keyboardOrPad.runKeyboardOrPad("SHOW")
    Call theKbOrPad.keyboardPadType("PAD", tb)
    'Call kbOrPad.keyboardPadType("PAD", tb)
End Sub
```

Also about the current error your are getting, you are trying to use  the [default instance of your Form1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233839.aspx) , it isn't the actual Form that you are running,  you can code around this by making the method you are trying to use as shared. Like this:

```
Public Shared Sub putIntoTextBox(ByRef what2Put As String, ByRef whatBox As TextBox)
    whatBox.Text = what2Put
End Sub
```

But however I would actually prefer to put it into your Module like this

```
Public Sub putIntoTextBox(ByRef what2Put As String, ByRef whatBox As TextBox)
    whatBox.Text = what2Put
End Sub
```

and call it like this

```
Call putIntoTextBox(btn.Text, theBoxName)
```

after making above changes your code worked.

Comment: Hey @Mark Hall! Adding the tb resulted in the same **nothing** at the end. And i am not sure how to implement the **Module scoped varibale...**.

Comment: Is all your code in the same class or are you using different classes

Comment: I'm using a **form** that has the textbox on it. A **keyboard Form** that has the keyboard layout buttons on it and a **class** that's in the middle of the 2 to communicate between them.

Comment: If i add **theBoxName.Text = "TEST"** to the **keyboardPadType function** then it puts "TEST" inside the textbox. However, once i use that same code in the **ClickLetters function** it gives me that error you see above in the image.???

Comment: @StealthRT I was able to get it working, look at my latest edit

Comment: Ugg! I still get the same error! :o( Can you zip up your project and paste the location here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12829/discussion-between-stealthrt-and-mark-hall)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should replace the ByRef with ByVal (anytime you don't know whether you should use one or the other, use ByVal).

Secondly, I believe you don't need the method, putIntoTextBox, I think you should be able to do that directly (might be threading problems that prevent it, but I don't think that's likely based on your description). You don't show where `Form1` is set (or even if it is), and that's another potential problem.

Finally, the better way to call back into the other class is to use a delegate/lambada.

(I know, no code, but you don't provide enough context for a working response, so I'm just giving text).

Comment: @StealthRT: if you're going to put that much up, go the rest of the way and put up the contents of the Designer files -- tried to turn it into a buildable project, but there are too many controls to recreate.  You also might want to prune it down to just what you need to show your problem.